# How can I return a BadRequest on Azure Mobile Services TableController GET template method?

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am using **Azure Mobile Services** (following the standard Azure *TodoItems tutorial*), and the most basic `GET` method that they provide is:

```
public IQueryable<MyModel> GetAllMyInfo()
{
    return Query(); 
}
```

This works, but I am trying to extend it so that the method will only return `MyModel` data for an authenticated user (identified by the `X-ZUMO-AUTH` authentication header standard for Mobile Service API calls). So I modified the code for:

```
public IQueryable<MyModel> GetAllMyInfo()
{
    // Get the current user
    var currentUser = User as ServiceUser;
    var ownerId = currentUser.Id;
    return Query().Where(s => s.OwnerId == ownerId); 
}
```

This also works when a valid auth token is passed. **However**, if an invalid auth header is passed, then the `currentUser` is `null`, and the query fails (obviously). So I am trying to check for null and return a `BadRequest` or a `403` HTTP code. Yet a simple `return BadRequest("Invalid authentication") gives a compilation error:

```
public IQueryable<MyModel> GetAllMyInfo()
{
    // Get the current user
    var currentUser = User as ServiceUser;
    if(currentUser == null) {
        return BadRequest("Database has already been created."); // This line gives a compilation error saying I need a cast.
    }
    var ownerId = currentUser.Id;

    return Query().Where(s => s.OwnerId == ownerId); 
}
```

**Does anyone know how to check for a valid authentication token and return a `403` on this method (which wants an `IQueryable` return type?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `[AuthorizeLevel]` attribute on this method to indicate that a valid token must be present in order for the method to be invoked. It will return a 401 if not.

So your full method would be:

```
[AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.User)]
public IQueryable<MyModel> GetAllMyInfo()
{
    // Get the current user
    var currentUser = User as ServiceUser;
    var ownerId = currentUser.Id;
    return Query().Where(s => s.OwnerId == ownerId); 
}
```

Please note that for the Azure Mobile Apps SDK (not Mobile Services), the above attribute is simply replaced with `[Authorize]`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late, but will document here for you and others that may come looking for a similar problem.
(While agreeing with Matt that a 403 could/should be achieved with a `[Authorize]` attribute, the question is regarding returning a different HttpStatusCode OR IQueryable)

I had a similar scenario where I needed to validate some query parameters and either return my results or a HttpError (in my case I wanted a 404 with content).

I found 2 ways, either keeping the return as `IQueryable<T>` and throwing a `HttpResponseException` or changing the return to `IHttpActionResult` and returning normal with HttpStatusCode or Ok(Data).
I found to prefer the later as throwing an Exception would be breaking the execution while in debug and not a very pleasant development experience.

#### Option 1 (Preferred)

```
//Adding Return annotation for API Documentation generation
[ResponseType(typeof(IQueryable<MyModel>))]
public IHttpActionResult GetAllMyInfo()
{
    // Get the current user
    var currentUser = User as ServiceUser;
    if(currentUser == null) {
        return BadRequest("Database has already been created.");
    }
    var ownerId = currentUser.Id;

    return Ok(Query().Where(s => s.OwnerId == ownerId)); 
}
```

#### Option 2 (Throwing Exception)

```
public IQueryable<MyModel> GetAllMyInfo()
{
    // Get the current user
    var currentUser = User as ServiceUser;
    if(currentUser == null) {
        throw new HttpResponseException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        // Or to add a content message:
        throw new HttpResponseException(new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) {
            Content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent("Database has already been created.")
        });
    }
    var ownerId = currentUser.Id;

    return Query().Where(s => s.OwnerId == ownerId); 
}
```